# Сгруппировать функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такой вот код:

```
class Test:
               
      def __init__(self, a):
          self.a = a;
          
      def abc(self):
          print(self.a);
      
      def cde(self):
          print(self.a);
```

Могу ли я как-то сгруппировать функции? Чтобы запускать их не так (например:)

```
a = Test('Hello');
a.abc();
```

А вот таким образом:

```
a = Test('Hello');
a.alphabet.abc();
a.alphabet.cde();
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Можно с внутренним классом:

```
class Test:
               
      def __init__(self, a):
          self.a = a
          self.alphabet = Test.Alphabet(self)
          
      class Alphabet:
            def __init__(self, test):
              self.test = test
              
            def abc(self):
              print(self.test.a)
      
            def cde(self):
              print(self.test.a)
              
              
              
a = Test('Hello')
a.alphabet.abc()
a.alphabet.cde()
```

Comment: Вот ещё есть варианты https://stackoverflow.com/q/45663249/7485582

Answer (score 1):

Если добавите в класс атрибут `alphabet`, то сможете.

```
class Test:
               
      def __init__(self, a):
          self.a = a;
          self.alphabet = self   # <<<<<<<<<<<<
          
      def abc(self):
          print(self.a);
      
      def cde(self):
          print(self.a);
          
a = Test('Hello');
a.alphabet.abc();
a.alphabet.cde();
```